# "Invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)" error for ä, ü, ö, ß which are Ascii!

Tags: ruby, encoding, ascii

My application needs to handle some international characters, namely ä, ü, ö and ß, which are still ascii.

When I tested the behavior of ruby when dealing with these chars, I got this error:

```
test.rb:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
test.rb:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

for this code:

```
puts "i like my chars: ä, ü, ö and ß!"
```

But the strange thing is: When using the Interactive Ruby Shell, I get no error!

**EDIT: In my application, I'm retrieving the data from an external api. The above code is just an example!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the magic comment `# coding: utf-8` at the beginning your your script (on the second line if you're using shebang).

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
# coding: utf-8

puts "i like my chars: ä, ü, ö and ß!"
```

Answer (score 11):

No, those characters *aren't* in ASCII. ASCII doesn't have any values above Unicode U+007F (decimal 127). See the [wikipedia ASCII entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for more details.

I suspect the interactive Ruby shell is taking the native encoding of your shell, rather than ASCII.

Do you have a way of specifying the encoding of your .rb file? If so, use that - or change your scripts so they genuinely *are* ASCII.

Comment: Oh thanks, I always thought ASCII includes 256 characters. But that doesn't solve my problem, because I'm retrieving the text from an external API...

Comment: @Vincent: If you're retrieving the text from an external API, why is it in your Ruby script? If it's really just test, leave it in a text file and load it from your Ruby script instead of putting it directly into the script.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not ASCII characters… They just happen to still be encoded in one byte in some legacy, ASCII-derived character sets. Most likely what is happening is that your source file is being saved as UTF-8 because it contains non-ASCII characters, and ruby is correctly handling this.

You're only getting away with it at the interactive prompt because your terminal is using some legacy character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To escape the characters for the ASCII encoding, use Unicode escape sequences:

```
puts "i like my chars: \u00E4, \u00FC, \u00F6 and \u00DF!"
```

*Ruby 1.9, anyway - I can't remember if this works in 1.8.*

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is removing the shebang line and running the script directly from ruby19 under macosx:

```
GreyJewel:Moralytics atma$ head -n1 moralytics 
**# coding: utf-8**
GreyJewel:Moralytics atma$ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
GreyJewel:Moralytics atma$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11]
GreyJewel:Moralytics atma$ ruby moralytics 
Το λεξικό που χρησιμοποιούμε έχει: 407117 λέξεις
Το λεξιλόγειο του χρήστη atmat εμπεριέχει: 3943 λέξεις συνολικά.
```

That worked. Using shebang causes the error. I can't tell for sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Add a magic comment in the script where you use non-ascii chars? It should go on top of the script.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

It worked for me like charm.

Or if you want to make the project wide, you have an option of [magic-encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) gem