# Phusion Passenger: ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, nginx, passenger

I am running a small Rails application under Ubuntu 14.04.1, using RVM to manage rubies. I have started using the Phusion Passenger (4.0.48)/nginx package so I can eventually serve multiple Rails applications from the same server (an older Dell laptop) in a low volume production environment. The application uses RSolr to make calls to a SOLR server to get text from old lab notebooks.

When I run the application using WEBrick or the Passenger standalone application server, it works fine. But when I run it under nginx, I get an error when certain text is returned from SOLR:

```
 ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
  <internal:prelude>:10:in 'synchronize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in 'process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in 'accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in 'main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in 'block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

I assume this is due to non-ASCII text being returned by SOLR to be presented on the display page. Since I don’t get this error when running under WEBrick or the passenger stand-alone server, I assume this is due to some configuration setting(s) related to how Passenger and nginix interact.  I've Googled around on this issue, most posts relate to using utf8 in your ruby code, or getting the correct ENV setting, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095845/when-run-bundle-get-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii), but nothing that seems to address this situation.

Any suggestions on where I should be peeking or troubleshooting, or where I should be changing a configuration setting? Thank you.

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9528509/1047207

Comment: @RAJ Fair point, I should have added to my question that I had previously tried the GEMFILE modification as you noted, as well as running `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` from the command line, then restartig nginx. No luck. :(

Comment: The link I cited in my original question was close, but the problem was that it told me to put `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8` and 
`Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8` in my Gemfile. The solution that worked for me was to put it in the environment.rb instead, as described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457996/how-do-i-fix-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit)

Comment: This problem occurred in a sinatra script of mine. In that case, putting the above Encoding specifications in the sinatra script solved it for me. Specifying it in the Gemfile did nothing.